# In Xilinx ISE, why can't I rename the net of some of my ports?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, ise

In Xilinx ISE, most of the time, when I want to rename the net of a certain port, I have no problem. I right-click on the I/O marker, click Rename Port, and I get the window for Rename Net. However, for some reason, when I do the same for some I/O markers, I get the window for Rename Bus. How can I get the window for Rename Net?

Comment: @MituRaj Might be using an older FPGA. Vivado might look better than ISE but it also seems to run a low slower.

Comment: @MituRaj I am using this for a school assignment. I do not have any choice in the tools I use.